# Write test-cases for python setuptools entry-points plugins

Tags: python, plugins, setuptools

I built a python application (the "host" app) that defines a [`setuptools`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#dynamic-discovery-of-services-and-plugins) entry-point, so that it can be extended.  Plugin-authors then have to add the following into their `setup.py` file:

```
setup(
    # ...
    entry_points = {
        'myapp.plugins': 
        ['plugin_1 = <foo.plugin.module>:<plugin-install-func>']
    }
)
```

In order to test my setup, i have to

- build a dummy wheel-package,
- use `pip` to install it,
- append new package's folder into `sys.path` and invoke `pkg_resources.working_set.add_entry(package_dir)`[*],
- only then i can check the expected behavior (run TCs),
- use `pip` to uninstall the package, and
- finally remove installed package folder from `sys.path`,

And a separate package is needed for each test-case, if different functionality must be validated.
This whole testing-rig is rather verbose and clumsy.

Is there a more elegant way to write test-cases for `setuptools` *entry-point* plugins?

[*] Note: Installing a *wheels* or using pip* in *develop mode* with `pip install -e <plugin-package>` would not activate the plugin **on the same interpreter** on *Linux*; or at least not without appending afterwards the package folder in `sys.path`. 
  On *Windows*, the above problem exists only on *develop mode*.

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? That your code consumes entry points properly? Or that it provides some documented entry points? Please describe the behavior you want to verify.

Comment: The functionality of the plugins i want to test is irrelevant. It is the testing rig that i care.  I need a reliable way to install packages from python code: using `import pip; pip.main('install foo')` does not work on all linux installations (eg travis).

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem and resolved by a dirty hack to build and 'pip install' the plugin package to test, into a tox's environment and run tests in that environment.

- a test script does dirty hack, that is, to build and install a wheel package and run tests: https://github.com/ssato/yamllint-plugin-example/blob/master/tests/test_plugin.sh
- tox configuration: https://github.com/ssato/yamllint-plugin-example/blob/master/tox.ini